# Using TTSearchBar with TTThumbsViewController

Tags: iphone, three20

I would like to layout a `TTSearchBar` above above a `TTThumbsViewController`. My current (failing) attempt involves my own `SearchViewController` that inherits from `TTViewController` and contains a reference to a `TTThumbsViewController` and `TTSearchBar`. In the `loadView` method, I instantiate both `TTThumbsViewController` and `TTSearchBar` and add them (actually, ..the `view` property of the TTTVC) as subviews. When the `SearchViewController` is pushed, neither the `TTThumbsViewController` nor the `TTSearchBar` are displayed.

I've just follwed the instructions at question [#2601484](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601484/why-does-my-tttableviewcontroller-not-appear) and gotten to same place as question [#2614079](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614079/ttthumbsviewcontroller-navigationcontroller-issue).

Am I going about this wrong? Is there a better way to add search to the `TTThumbsViewController`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how I'd go about it. I would subclass TTThumbsViewController and add the SearchBar to that subclass. There's no built-in search for TTThumbsViewController, I should look into creating that.

Also, for problem #2, that's usually a result of not using TTNavigator. The TTThumbsViewController is likely looking for the TTNavigator NavigationBar which doesn't exist. You can fix that in your TTThumbsViewController subclass as well by overriding things like:

```
- (void)updateTableLayout {
  self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(TTBarsHeight()+4, 0, 0, 0);
  self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(TTBarsHeight(), 0, 0, 0);
}

// TTTableViewController
- (CGRect)rectForOverlayView {
  return TTRectContract(CGRectOffset([super rectForOverlayView], 0, TTBarsHeight()-_tableView.top),
                        0, TTBarsHeight());
}
```

It's likely the TTBarsHeight() that's causing problems. I had to do this for one of my own projects.

Comment: Thanks, both recommendations worked well. I had to adjust the insets by TTBarsHeight()-30 for one controller and TTBarsHeight()-60 for another, which seems pretty wonky. I'll have to look into if I'm doing anything strange. I am using TTNavigator, so I wouldn't think that'd be the problem.